# Installing windows software on Mac using Virtual Box

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I need to install windows application on Mac using Virtualbox.

I want to know is it required to install full Windows virtual machine or not, is there facility to run windows application without installing windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX) (Wine Is Not an Emulator). It's a compatibility layer that runs on OSX (and many other OSes including most other *nixes) and allows you to run most Windows programs natively, without virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover/). It works the same way as The Electric Muffin's suggestion, but it is much easier to use and set up than Wine.

It essentially creates a minimal Windows emulation system that will allow you to run most software without having to actually install Windows. You can check their [list of compatible applications](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/) or just try installing it on your own.